# How to make in c# methods on call to stop to continue (like Unity UNet Commands, RPCs)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wonder how actually Unity handle with their Network System UNet methods which do not execute the content (code) in the method. For example: If you have

```
[Command]
void CmdPrint()
{
    PrintSomeTextHere();
}
```

and use CmdPrint on the client the PrintSomeTextHere() will not be executed (but on the Server it will). How it is possible to do this in C#? Is there maybe something in background (like reflections and methodinfo) which prevents to execute the method?

Comment: UNet is an opaque black box that few people actually know how to use. Unity is deprecating the entire system and replacing it "soon."

Comment: I know. I am making my own network system. I already made even rpc functions and I am finished soon with basic stuff.. But the question is more behind the scenes about c#. I just remembered about it while I was coding and had this question not answered. Btw "mirror" is a copy of unet and they made own transport layer. So is very good alternate to UNet and even better. They are still making new features.

Comment: Tho there is some codegeneration based on attributes

Comment: You'll have to look into making your own attributes. Good luck I have no idea how that works.

Comment: @Draco18s I have already my own attributes. I can use [ClientRpc] and [ServerRpc] to make remote calls. To be clear. My question is not about unity. It is about c# the way how that is possible because its very interesting. caxapexac already mentioned codegeneration

Comment: *`My question is not about unity.`* Then don't tag it Unity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came back to this question and I could answer it now. I first thought it is c# based solution. I thought in c# we are maybe able to stop current call of a method (like you would add "return" to the first line") and you could track or register it to an event something like "on call but before execution -> do something". But after researching it again what changes happens to the code. @caxapexac has already mentioned.

**Answer to the question**

Unity itself is just changing the code after the compile but we don't see it.

This Code

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(shootKey))
{
    CmdFire();
}
```

Will be changed after the compile to

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(shootKey))
{
    CallCmdFire();
}
```

But the CmdFire is still defined.

```
[Command]
void CmdFire() ...
```

And the CallCmdFire is generated / added.

```
public void CallCmdFire()
{
    if (base.isServer)
    {
        CmdFire();
        return;
    }
    NetworkWriter writer = NetworkWriterPool.GetWriter();
    SendCommandInternal(typeof(Tank), "CmdFire", writer, 0);
    NetworkWriterPool.Recycle(writer);
}
```

Very clever designed.

Comment: great analysis ;)